# Setting Python Counter placeholder values

Tags: python, while-loop, counter, placeholder, zero

I am trying to read a csv file line by line using counter in Python. These are the 3 lines in that csv file:

```
02,17,25,32,42,49,04
06,20,23,29,35,53,57
13,14,18,19,21,36,53
```

What I am trying to do is +=1 the numbers that DON'T appear in a list of 1 to 60. I set a range of 1 - 60 up beforehand, set them to zero, open up a text file and read it line by line:

```
import collections

c = collections.Counter(range(1,60))
c = collections.Counter({x:0 for x in c})

with open('lottoresults.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
```

Next I want to split each line into it's comma separated values. For every Counter value that matches the line's CS Value, set Counter value to 0, otherwise iterate the Counter's value up by 1.

```
for n in line.strip().split(","):
    while c['%d'] % n:
        c['%d'] = 0
    else:
        c['%d'] += 1
```

I get the following error though:

> ```
> while c['%d'] % n:
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'str'
> ```

Could someone please help explain what I am doing wrong?

To clarify:

I have an initial Count of numbers in an array: 
(1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0)

I then run one line and get the numbers 1, 2. The Count should now show:
(1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1)

I then run one line and get the numbers 3, 4. The Count should now show:
(1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 2)

i.e. all the numbers that did not occur, are incremented by 1, while those that were pulled, reset to 0.

Comment: `n` is a string, convert it to int: `int(n)`

Comment: Thanks, that did help sort of. Gets me an output, but seems that matching up between the c and f variables isn't happening. Counter just added to it's elements:

({...58: 1, 59: 1, '%d': 1})

Comment: @GeraldJabroni what exactly is the output you want, e.g. for those lines you've provided? It isn't clear to me why you need a counter, if you simply want to add 1 to every number not `1 <= n <= 60`...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what I want to do is to count the number of times a specific number does not occur, and if it does occur, reset it's count to 0.

If I have a count of each number: 
(1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0)

and I pull the numbers 1, 2, I want the count to change to:
(1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1)

i.e. all the numbers that did not occur, are incremented by 1, while those that were pulled, reset to 0.